# Unable to connect to the remote server but works when fiddler is running metro app

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, fiddler, .net-4.5

I have a strange issue, I am trying to retrieve a XML string from a network computer and it works when I am outside of my own network but when I am on the same network I get exceptions such as:

```
+       $exception  {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}  System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.2.214:8080
```

the code I am using is:

```
Uri URL = new Uri(SabURL + QueueStatusURL + API);
            string myURL = URL.AbsolutePath;



            var xmlResults = XDocument.Load(URL.OriginalString.ToString());
```

The strange part is that when I run Fiddler4 it works just fine, what does Fiddler do that makes it start working? Is this some sort of proxy issue and if so how would I handle it?

Comment: If you copy-paste `URL.OriginalString.ToString()` in a browser, do you see the XML ?

Comment: I assume you checked, that all the URLs are correct, so i'd look if there's a Proxy configured for your System (maybe an automatic Proxy) or if Fiddler chaines up an Proxy (see the help window of Fiddler) and if it chaines one, you could check if your application uses that Proxy (use NetMon for example and check target IP)

Comment: I can go directly to the URL and I get an XML output in IE/Chrome and like I said, if I am outside of the network and I target my machine at home it works just fine so there is a issue within my home network somewhere but I don't know what it is

Comment: I've got the same problem; but I discovered that exceptions are only thrown when a local ip address is used (192.x.x.x). When I test it with a public ip (which points to the same site) I get the same exception.

Comment: Same deal, my app is meant to use both local and remote endpoints :|

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the capability of Private Networks, it worked for me

[image]

Comment: Thanks Haris. I also did this to get a Win8 Store app to work when sending HttpWebRequests to my intranet test server. Okay, as long as one remembers to uncheck for actual store submission!

Comment: @Stonetip where can I find this option

Comment: @ralphspoon You'll find this setting in the Solution Explorer > Package.appxmanifest (just double-click to open and edit)

Answer (score 2):

This is a behavior issue in IE. if a request doesnt resolve, it will not show the response and not navigate to the page. Chrome on the other hand doesnt care if a request doesnt resolve but shows the URL nonetheless with a message that server not found or similar.

What fiddler does is act as a proxy when it is turned on. So wwhen you have fiddler running, it tries to resolve a request and then passes an html page to IE even if there was an error. so IE always shows something when fiddler is running since IE doesnt try to handle requests itself.

There is no known way of changing this behavior unfortunately.

Comment: This is a great explanation of why it worked when it did, thank you